# rails Can't save serialized object in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I have a serialized object :address in Hotel class. When I'm trying to save data using the form, it all saves fine. All except :address. No errors, nothing... Tried different variants, please help.

Here is my code:

migrations

```
class CreateHotels < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :hotels do |t|
      t.string  :title
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :stars
      t.text    :room
      t.decimal :price
      t.text    :address

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :hotels, [:user_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

hotel.rb

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 80 }
  validates :stars, presence: true
  validates :room, length: { maximum: 800 }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  serialize :address, Hash
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@hotel) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>

  <%= f.label :stars %>
  <%= f.text_field :stars %>

  <%= f.label :room, "Room description" %>
  <%= f.text_area :room, size: "20x10" %>

  <%= f.label :price %>
  <%= f.number_field :price %>

  <%= f.fields_for :address, OpenStruct.new(f.object.address || {}) do |o| %>
    <%= o.label :country %>
    <%= o.text_field :country %>

    <%= o.label :state %>
    <%= o.text_field :state %>

    <%= o.label :city %>
    <%= o.text_field :city %>

    <%= o.label :street %>
    <%= o.text_field :street %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: As for me I would generate separate model Address, which will belongs_to Hotel (of course, Hotel has_one address). IMHO, this way would be less complicated.

Comment: @RedZagogulin, that looks easier. So, I guess I'll need a new table Address that will contain hotel_id, right?

Comment: Yes. Hotel "has_one" Address and Address "belongs_to" Hotel, therefore in hotels table - address_id, in address table - hotels_id.

Answer (score 1):

In your hotels_controller.rb have you permitted address params?

```
    params.require(:hotel).permit(address: [:country, :state, :city, :street])
```